# Clone a git Repo with GitGutter

Tags: git, clone, packages, sublime-text-3

I'm new to sublime3 and trying to use GitGutter for version control and I don't know how to clone with GitGutter package a Git Project. How do I do this with SSH access under Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am the creator of GitGutter,  it does not do what you are trying to do. It simply marks changes in the gutter. You need the plugin https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git to do that.